# How to get the callback of an async function in javascript

Tags: javascript

Definitely a duplicate question, but I can't find the answer on google/stackoverflow/freecodecamp chat.

How do I get the callback of an async function?

```
import { should } from 'chai';
import { Customer } from '../../data/models';

describe('Customers Server', () => {
  it('Create a customer', async () => {
    const createCustomer = await Customer.create({ email: 'test@gmail.com' });
    should.exist(createCustomer);
  });
});
```

createCustomer is the function. Everything I'm researching says that createCustomer is the callback... but it's not. It returns the function .create instead. Where do I get the callback?

Here's an error message I found:

```
For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.
```

And [here's an example of using done()](https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit/blob/fd2845f277683eb7cc1415f6ebaee04b625ca86b/src/core/passport.js) (with something called 'fooBar'), but I'm not sure how to use it with my tests.

**Update** Trying @bhantol 's suggestion... (Passing done through async as a parameter and then calling done() after 'should')

```
it('Create a customer', async (done) => {
  const createCustomer = await Customer.create({ email: 'test@gmail.com' });
  should.exist(createCustomer);
  done();
```

Gives the same error in terminal:

```
Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.
```

Comment: Three languages mixed into one code. Remarkable.

Comment: hahaha. I'm really pumped to start writing async functions! It seems better than nested stuff, even if you "modularize" the functions into separate bits.

Comment: The problem may not be `create` It's the `it` which has async(). Pass done through it and call done() after the should statement.

Comment: from the website www.callbackhell.com "Async functions are a proposed ES7 feature that will further wrap generators and promises in a higher level syntax. Check them out if that sounds interesting to you."